# Отправка двух email писем средствами php

Tags: php, email

Есть скрипт отправляющий мне (админу) на почту письмо с значениями   полей из формы. 
Хочу реализовать отправку второго письма (клиенту).
С текстом о принятии заявки и скорой связи с ним, от почты на хостинге , при этом почта клиента должна быть взята из формы и желательно без подключения библиотек.
Я новичок в php и не совсем понимаю как это правильно реализовать, всем спасибо!

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $in_form_email  = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; width: auto;'><b>$key:</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px;width: 100%;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; width: auto;'><b>$key:</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px;width: 100%;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 50%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$in_form_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
?>
```

Comment: Если вы делали скрипт самостоятельно, то у вас не должно возникнуть проблем с вашим вопросом. Если делали не сами, то обратитесь к тому, кто делал этот скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки на две почты просто запустите ещё раз отправку на другой адрес $to, и измените как вам угодно тело письма

```
<?php

$to = ""; // Адрес на который нужно отправить Электронный адрес
//Получение данных с формы
$name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$phone = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));

$subject = 'Заголовок'; // заголовок письма
$sender="{$product} <noreply@{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}>"; // Адрес отправителя
//Кодировка отправитель
$header="Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
From: {$sender}
";
//Тело письма
$message = "ФИО: {$name}
Контактный телефон: {$phone}

Сайт: {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}
Время: ".date("m.d.Y H:i:s")."
IP отправителя: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
$success_url = 'success.php?name='.$name.'&phone='.$phone.'';//адрес переадресации на страницу после отправки

$verify = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);//отправка, если отправлено то в переменную $verify установится значение true
if ($verify == 'true'){
    echo("<script>document.location.href = '{$success_url}';</script>");//переход на страницу 
    exit;
}
else
    {
    echo '<h1 style="color:red;">Произошла ошибка!</h1>';//вывод ошибки если письмо не отправлено
    }
?>
```